# ShedLock SchedulingConfigurer With Multiple Jobs

Tags: scheduled-tasks, shedlock

I have the following code where i get a list of Cronjobs from the DB and execute them programmatically using SchedulingConfigurer.

Any pointers on spinning each task with its own LockableTaskScheduler?

I tried with the below code, but it does not work.

Shedlock is not creating an entry for each cron in the DB, its just using the last Cron.

```
@Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {

        Map<String, TaskConfig> cronTasks = findJobs();

        for (Map.Entry<String, TaskConfig> cronTask : cronTasks.entrySet()) {
            taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(getScheduler(cronTask.getValue()));
            log.info("Registering cron task for scheduling: {}, cronExpression: {}", cronTask.getKey(), cronTask
                    .getValue());
            taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(() -> executeTask(cronTask.getValue()), cronTask.getValue().getCronTrigger());
        }

    }

    public LockableTaskScheduler getScheduler(TaskConfig value) {

        LockConfigurationExtractor lockConfigurationExtractor = task -> Optional
                .of(new LockConfiguration(Instant.now(), value.getConfigEntity().get_id(), Duration.ofMinutes(3), Duration
                        .ofMinutes(2)));

        LockManager lockManager = new DefaultLockManager(lockProvider, lockConfigurationExtractor);
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("MyThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        scheduler.initialize();
        return new LockableTaskScheduler(scheduler, lockManager);
    }
```